# High-volume logging in C++

Tags: c++, file

I have a code that writes logs to disk, at times many many logs per second.

Generally the code keep a file open (fopen "a+") uses fputs to write a single log and then flushes.

I know the flush is not efficient but it is important for our logic.

when I did perf i saw the following:
[image]

As you can see it heavily spending time in kernel modebut it and a big part of it it due to lock
I tried to use fputs_unlocked and fflush_unlocked but it didn't change anything.
How can I write without locking the file? is there anything in the process of writing that can be done better to get better performance?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't show images of text. Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions.

Comment: The kernel works the way that the kernel works. Yes, file writing is expensive. And this is precisely why iostreams uses stream buffers, to buffer up output and only write large chunks at a time, and the obsolete C library's `FILE`-based output this code apparently uses does basically the same thing. The `_unlocked` functions that were mentioned were for something related to multi-threaded code's considerations, which is completely irrelevant here. Flushing is expensive. Which is precisely the reason why output is buffered by default.

Comment: But shouldn't the unlocked version remove at least the top part which is the _raw_spin_lock?